# How do I know what version of the .net framework I need to build for

Tags: c#, .net, dll, build

I have a bunch of solutions in C# that I've been handed. There is production code on the server, and I have a version of it on a local dev machine. I make a code change, and build the dlls. When I try to copy the dlls to the server, it gives me errors like:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'myfile.dll' or one of its dependencies. 
This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime 
and cannot be loaded."
```

One of the issues is that the projects that I use for building ORM, data, and business logic are not on the server, but are on my local, and I can use them to build dlls, but it isn't helpful when I can't tell what the server is using either. Where do you find out what versions it runs and how to build to match? I know this is my own ignorance in not knowing how the .net framework works, the different versions, how to build for the right one (32-bit vs 64-bit a concern too?) and get things to work. I have looked around a bit, but no where seems to explain this.

Comment: Of which IIS version are we talking?

Comment: @AndreCalil Usually IIS7, sometimes 6. I have many projects where this is a problem, but most don't require much dll building, html code at most. When they do, I have major issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32 or 64 bits should not bother you. To find the framework version, you must look for the website or virtual directory at **IIS**.

I don't have a Windows Server here, but it's something like this:

1. Open IIS Management tool
2. Find your website or virtual directory, right click and go to properties
3. There should be a tab named .Net (or something like it)
4. At this tab, there is a combo with the available runtime versions binded to IIS. The current is the one you're using.

These steps are for IIS 6. For IIS 7 it's mostly the same, but they don't call it "properties" window, it's "Advanced something".

I'm sorry for not having the proper details, but you'll be able to find it.

Comment: In IIS, the servers say v2.0 classic, but the source code seems to target either 3.5 or 4.0 in the web.config and in properties. Does this need to match?

Comment: Open windows explorer and point to `c:\windows\.Net Framework\Framework`. If there's a folder for `3.5`, then your target version should be 3.5 (take care with SP1 on your dev machine, server may not have it). 3.5 runs on the top of 2.0

Comment: So, I can build 3.5 dlls for use on a 2.0 IIS7 server because 3.5 is really 2.0 dressed up with extra features? Is that accurate?

Comment: .Net 3.5 framework is an extension of 2.0. Even if you have it installed on the server and binded to IIS, you won't be able to select it at IIS, it'll show as 2.0. That's why I pointed you to take a look at the installation dir at `C:\Windows\.Net Framework\...`

Comment: The folder on my server was actually C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework but finding the 3.5 folder and changing the target on my projects did the trick, thanks.

Comment: @rncrtr Yes, that's it. Sorry for not being so precise and thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

To change the target framework of your project in vs2k10: Open project properties -> Application tab -> Target framework(its combobox with available versions)

To check/change the framework version on your server(it is for IIS 7.0 version):

1. Open IIS manager.
2. Click the “Application Pools” node.
3. Find the corresponding application pool that your web site/virtual directory use(by default there is a “DefaultAppPool” application pool).
4. Right click the application pool, and then select “Advanced Settings”
5. There should be “.NET Framework Version”